# How to sum up the corresponding elements for each element of a cell array

Tags: matlab, for-loop, matrix, vectorization

I have a cell array C, each element is an N1xN2xN3 matrix.
I need to sum up all the correspondent elements in these cells, and result in a N1xN2xN3 matrix res, whose element equals to

```
res=zeros(size(C{1}));
for i=1:n_cell
    res=res.+C{i}
end
```

Is there a more efficient way to do it(without for loop?)?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can concatenate the matrices along the 4th dimension and then sum along that.

```
res = sum(cat(4, C{:}), 4);
```

Here is a general solution for any dimension of elements of `C`

```
res = sum(cat(ndims(C{1}) + 1, C{:}), ndims(C{1}) + 1);
```

If you're using octave you can simply use `plus`:

```
res = plus(C{:});
```

Unfortunately this last option won't work on MATLAB because `plus` in MATLAB only accepts two input arguments.

Comment: Great! Thank you very much!